# Need to extract the values that follow a pattern in the string in Java

Tags: java

I have a string as below:

```
String a= "member;range=12001-*: CN=marimar,OU=Employees,OU=Cisco 
Users,DC=cisco,DC=com, CN=cadautel,OU=Employees,OU=Cisco 
Users,DC=cisco,DC=com CN=rajaki,OU=Employees,OU=Cisco 
Users,DC=cisco,DC=com";
```

I need to get the values of the CN attribute like 'marimar','cadautel,'rajaki' .

I have to use Java 7 to do that and hence I cannot use String.split() Can anybody help me out to come up with the logic.

Thanks!

Comment: "*I have to use Java 7 to do that and hence I cannot use String.split()*" => huh?

Comment: Java 7 `String` does have the `split()` method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String) - your *"hence"* doesn't seem to apply

Comment: Oops! You guys are correct. My apologies. But, I cannot use String.split() because my Java version in production environment doesn't support the split method.

Comment: Can you guys pls help me out to come up with a logic without the split method. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String#split` isn't the best tool for this job.  Use a pattern matcher instead:

```
String a = "member;range=12001-*: CN=marimar,OU=Employees,OU=Cisco
    Users,DC=cisco,DC=com, CN=cadautel,OU=Employees,OU=Cisco
    Users,DC=cisco,DC=com CN=rajaki,OU=Employees,OU=Cisco
    Users,DC=cisco,DC=com";
String pattern = "CN=([^,]+)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(a);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("CN attribute: " + m.group(1) );
}
```

### Demo